# TYPO3 - Scheduler task with custom query

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-6.2.x

I'm using TYPO3 6.2.
I created a custom Extbase Task in order to execute it automatically every day.

```
<?php

namespace Myextension\Scheduler;

use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility;

class Task extends \TYPO3\CMS\Scheduler\Task\AbstractTask {


    public function execute()
    {

        // Custom MySQL query here

    }

}

?>
```

I need to develop a complicated mysql query with a lot of conditions, datas and joins : is it possible not to use  `$GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->exec_SELECTquery` but a method like `$GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->sql_query(' SELECT * FROM ... ')` ?

Comment: See https://gist.github.com/jaguerra/5533655

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[EDIT]:
**This answer is related to old and outdated versions of TYPO3** and not working anymore in current versions as the old abstraction layer `$GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']` was [replaced by DBAL in TYPO3 v9](https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/main/en-us/Changelog/9.0/Breaking-80929-TYPO3_DBMovedToExtension.html).

---

Yes, that's definitely possible.

This is the complete function:

```
/**
 * Executes query
 * MySQLi query() wrapper function
 * Beware: Use of this method should be avoided as it is experimentally supported by DBAL. You should consider
 * using exec_SELECTquery() and similar methods instead.
 *
 * @param string $query Query to execute
 * @return boolean|\mysqli_result|object MySQLi result object / DBAL object
 */
public function sql_query($query) {
    $res = $this->query($query);
    if ($this->debugOutput) {
        $this->debug('sql_query', $query);
    }
    return $res;
}
```

And you find it in the file:

```
typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Database/DatabaseConnection.php
```

And you can call it like you wrote:

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->sql_query(' SELECT * FROM ... ')
```